# Can summoned creatures cast summon creatures?

Tags: open-legend, boons

The boon *Summoned creature* says:

> You create or summon a temporary NPC companion that is under your
>   control, though of limited intelligence. Your minion's statistics are
>   determined by the power level of this boon. You may assign the
>   attributes as you see fit among the following: Agility, Fortitude,
>   Might, Perception, Energy, and Entropy.  (...) On each of your
>   following turns, your minion acts on your initiative count according
>   to your direction, receiving the usual assortment of actions.

As Energy and Entropy are both attributes for Summon Creature, can they summon creatures as well?

For instance, if my Energy score is 9, and I dual cast it to get two beings with energy score 7, can they make a creature with Energy 5, and they make a creature with Energy 3? If so, now I have 6 creatures that can each inflict Persistent Damage, which is a lot of damage (this is assuming everything boon cast works).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**You can do that, but it's not particularly OP.**

Yes, this is possible.  It's not utterly amazing, though.  You may have six creatures who can inflict Persistent Damage, but two of them have stats of six less than yours, and nonstellar defenses.  It's also not free.  They're eating all of your higher-tier boon sustains, after all.  Just by dual-casting creatures, without the cascades, you could have one of those creatures Aura Resistance (to whatever kind of resistance you were most concerned by) and give a nice little survivability buff to the entire team.  You could let the other one render itself Insubstantial and go around handing out Entropy banes, or perhaps indulge in a minor demoralizing aura to make it even harder for the enemies to damage you.  There are *lots* of ways to use Summon Boons.  Just summoning more things with them isn't particularly any stronger than using summoning in the first place is.

Really, this isn't a matter of "Cascade summon OP".  It's the fact that 9 in just about anything is pretty strong if you leverage it right.